# AngularJS - How to bind to an ngRepeat element inside a directive

Tags: javascript, web, angularjs, closures, directive

In my directive I have a template with ng-repeat,

```
 ...return {
       template:'<div id="wrapper"><ul><li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</li></ul></div>',
       compile:function (tElement, tAttrs) {

        return function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              //bind item mouse event to a closure function
        }
    }
    }...
```

I would like to bind each element of the repeater with a function inside my  directive, what would be the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to screate isolated scope and pass items to directive by adding `scope: { items: '='}` to directive definition object, then add handler to each item:

```
<span ng-click='clicked(item)'>{{item.name}}<span>
```

And in link function:

```
scope.clicked = function(item) { .. Do thmthng with item...};
```

And use it as `<directive items='items' ...>`